SQL "incompatible data type in criteria expression" error
I am doing a simple SELECT query by clicking on the month in a ComboBox. It lists the people who work in this month.
I have the month table (Num_Month "PK") and the person_month table (Num_Month "FK") both of integer type, and I checked well at execution, but I always get the error:

incompatible data type in criteria expression

I tried with TDBLookupComboBox to import months from the month table but the same error appears.
With Q1 do
Begin
  Close;
  Sql.Clear;
  Sql.Add('Select * from Person_Month Where Num_month ='+QuotedStr(ComboBox1.Text));
  Open;
  DBGrid2.DataSource.DataSet.Open;
End;


SQL Injection alert - you should not concatenate together your SQL statements - use parametrized queries instead to avoid SQL injection - check out Little Bobby Tables

https://translate.google.com/?sl=lg&tl=en&text=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.4each.com.br%2Fthreads%2Fsql-incompatible-data-type-in-criteria-expression-error.63803%2F&op=translate

If your column is type integer, then you don't quote the value. Try this instead:
Sql.Add('Select * from Person_Month Where Num_month = ' + ComboBox1.Text);

If you're using user input at all, you should be using parameterized queries instead.
SQL.Add('Select * from Person_Month Where Num_Month = :Num');

// If the Num_Month column is a numeric type, you can use AsString -
// it will raise an exception if the text can't be converted to
// a number.
ParamByName('Num').AsString := ComboBox1.Text;

Now that you've indicated to Remy in the comments that you're using ADO (which should have been in your post originally), the use of parameters is different. If the column is defined as a numeric type, you don't have to convert it first - if you pass a value that can't be converted to a number, the database driver will raise an exception.
Params.ParamByName('Num').Value := ComboBox1.Text;


"you should be using parameterized queries instead" - agreed, for example: Sql.Add('Select * from Person_Month Where Num_month = :month'); ParamByName('month').AsInteger := StrToInt(ComboBox1.Text);. Whether you do or don't use parameters, always sanitize user input. In this case, if the user tries to enter invalid input then StrToInt() will catch it. Even if you don't use parameters, eg: Sql.Add('Select * from Person_Month Where Num_month = ' + IntToStr(StrToInt(ComboBox1.Text)));

it doesn't work , (missing operator or semicolon for ".AsInteger")
(undeclared identifier for "ParamByName")
Sql.Add('Select * from Person_Month Where Num_month = :month'); ParamByName('month').AsInteger := StrToInt(ComboBox1.Text);

My answer doesn't use AsInteger. If you're addressing someone else, you need to let them know by directing your comment to him using the at-sign + username convention, as in @RemyLebeau. This will put a notification in their mailbox.

@fatehdjelti what is the class type of Q1? My example is based on tbe assumption you are using TQuery or some other standard Delphi query component. This kind of detail should have been included in your question. Most query components have properties related to parameterizing the SQL query.

@Remy Lebeau  i 'm using TADOQuery ,  the code should be : Parameters.ParambyName but i stil get error (missing operator or semicolon for ".AsInteger")   in fact it is not  the first time i use this methode it works correctly now i don't know where is the error!

@fatehdjelti for ADO, you have to use .Value instead. So, my earlier example would be: With Q1 do begin ... Sql.Add('Select * from Person_Month Where Num_month = :month'); Parameters.ParamByName('month').Value := StrToInt(ComboBox1.Text); ... end;

@Remy Lebeau,  for the combobox there is no input from the user, the user must choose the month number in the combobox list, I made a loop to load all the months existing in the month table (Q1, Q2 - TADOQuery class) the code is as follows: (OnFormActivate) close;sql.Clear;  sql.Add('select Num_Month from Month Order by Num_Month DESC') ; Open;if Q2.RecordCount > 0 then begin Q2.First; While Not Q2.Eof do Begin ComboBox1.Items.Add(DataSource2.DataSet.FieldValues['Num_Month']); Q2.Next;

@fateh: I posted it for you two full days ago, and you've totally ignored it to have an inappropriate conversation with a different user. You've wasted my time and effort, without even a thank you or an acknowledgement of my efforts. That's not the way this site works, and it's rude and insulting.

@RemyLebeau: Please do me a favor and move this conversation to chat, so that the annoyance of getting pinged while you have your inappropriate conversation on my answer stops. It's bad enough that the OP is ignoring the effort that I put into writing an answer, without the constant annoyance of getting notified every time you two post something that is irrelevant to this answer.

@Ken White  not that sir I was on duty for 24 consecutive hours I couldn't answer at the time, now I'm trying to apply what you and Mr. Remy told me, thank you very much and I'm still waiting for your help

@KenWhite wow, excuse me for trying to be helpful. Fine, I'm done. Moving this to chat is not an option as the OP doesn't have enough reputation points to join a chat room. The OP can post a new question if they want to continue this topic. I'm out, peace! ✌️

@fatehdjelti: I've given you my help. I've written the code for you (twice). You've had enough time during your busy schedule to contact Remy several times, so you're not that tied up with work.

@KenWhite, you have all my apologies sir
